# time compare with H:i in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

I am trying to compare a time to current time, and have failed in many attempts now.

I have tried comparing
date('U') to '08:00',
time() to '08:00',
date('H:i') to '08:00'
strrotime('08:00' ) to time() or date('U')

and as below in my latest attempt, trying to compare
strrotime('08:00'.':00' ) to time() or date('U')

If I leave my value as '08:00' I get an error that it can't be converted to time, and if I try strtotime I get an error that it expected a string for argument and not a dateobject like I passed... I passed no object, just a variable containing a string '08:00'...

code from my latest attempt:

```
if ($sleepSettings <> null) {
    if (is_array($sleepSettings)) {
        $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['wakeup'] = $sleepSettings['wakeup_s'];
        $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['sleep'] = $sleepSettings['sleep_s'];

        if (strtotime($sleepSettings['wakeup'] . ':00') < time() && time() < strtotime($sleepSettings['sleep'] . ':00')) {
            $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['asleep'] = false;
        } else {
            $containerHelper[$c->getId()]['asleep'] = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see if the current time is *between* the wakeup and sleep times, Jessica's answer won't do. Assuming $wakeup_time is something like '07:00' and $bed_time is something like '23:00', you would want to apply them to any day, so comparing to time() won't work. You need to get $timeNow and compare the hours and minutes separately. Something like:

```
$wakeup_time = explode(':', $wakeup_time);
$bed_time    = explode(':', $bed_time);
$timeNow = array(date('H'), date('i'));
// the three times are separate hour and minute elements
if (($timeNow[0] == $wakeup_time[0] && $timeNow[1] >= $wakeup_time[1] ||
     $timeNow[0]  > $wakeup_time[0] ) &&
    ($timeNow[0] == $bed_time[0] && $timeNow[1] < $bed_time[1] ||
     $timeNow[0]  < $bed_time[0]) ) {
   // awake
} else {
   // asleep
}
```

That's one way. You could also synthesize a time() for wakeup and bed times, using today's date:

```
$wakeup_timestamp = strtotime(date('Y-M-d ').$wakeup_time);
$bed_timestamp    = strtotime(date('Y-M-d ').$bed_time);
if (time() >= $wakeup_timestamp && time() < $bed_timestamp) {
  // awake
} else {
  // asleep
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime` wants to convert into a unix timestamp, which includes Date and Time.

All you want to do is compare the current time to that time?

```
<?php
$nowTime = date('H:i');
var_dump($sleepSettings['wakeup'].':00' == $nowTime); 
// Should be a boolean either true or false.
```

You can compare the two strings.

In fact, if you're just trying to do the hour (since you're adding the `:00`), you can just use `date('H')` and not add `':00'`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to compare just the time part of date. The time() function  will return seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT) and that includes the day, so from your code you are comparing the string '08:00' to number of seconds from January 1 1970.

If you want to compare just the time part of the date, convert everything to minutes. ex:

```
$wake_hour = 8;
$wake_mim = 0;
$wake_total = ($wake_hour * 60) + $wake_mim;

$sleep_hour = 10;
$sleep_mim = 0;
$sleep_total = ($sleep_hour * 60) + $sleep_mim;

$now_hour = date('H');
$now_mim = date('i');

$now_total = ($now_hour * 60) + $now_mim;

if ($now_total > $wake_total && $now_total < $sleep_total) {
    echo 'Wake up and conquer the world!!!';
}
```